# Getting original list from string of list python

Tags: python, list, input

I am pretty confused here.
I have a function that has a list as an argument. It then does list-specific functions on it. Here is an example:

```
def getValues( my_list ):
    for q in my_list:
        print(q)
```

But, I get my list from USER INPUT like this:

```
a_list = input("Please enter a list.  ")
getValues(a_list)
```

The built-in input() function returns a string, not a list. My solution is to take that string of the list and turn it back into a list.

Only I don't know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its what that `ast.literal_eval` is for  :

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
[1, 2, 3]
```